# Input Current to Output Current for a step-up voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am buying one of the many step-up regulators available on Amazon, the [Icstation 2577](http://a.co/dSPKsh2).

In my project plan, I will be using either a 150mah or 300mah 3.7V 25C lipo battery. I will be stepping that up to ~5V and drawing between 1-1.5A on the 5V output.

What I am trying to figure out, which I can't locate the seemingly simple answer to from searching around, is how the input current will relate to the output current. If I am drawing 1.5A at 5V from the regulator output, what can I expect the input current from the battery to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The power formula \$ P = VI \$ gives the relationship between power, voltage and current.
- Your required output is \$ P_{OUT} = 5 \times 1.5 = 7.5 \; W \$.
- Assuming you could get a booster with 85% efficiency your input power requirement will be \$ P_{IN} = \frac {7.5}{0.85} = 8.8 \; W \$.
- Going back to the power formula your input current at 3.7 V will be \$ I_{IN} = \frac {P_{IN}}{V_{IN}} = \frac {8.8}{3.7} = 2.4 \; A\$.
- Run time will be given by \$ hours = \frac {mAh}{mA} = \frac {300}{2400} = \frac {1}{6} = 10 \; minutes\$.

At this point you need to refer to the battery data sheet. The 300 mAh is probably a 10 hour discharge rate - i.e., 30 mA for 10 hours. At higher currents and particularly when exceeding the one-hour discharge rate as you intend to the capacity will be greatly reduced - possibly to about 50%.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct and detailed answer. I will probably refer to your answer a lot in the future :)

Comment: Make that 5minutes or less, for derating from the 0.1C capacity calculation.

Comment: Good point. Done.

Answer (score 2):

The current from the battery wil be 2.5A or more.

You are boosting by a factor of 1.5. The current from the battery will go up by the same factor, so 2.25A from the battery assuming 1.5A at 5V.  Then there are losses in the regulator, a good bit over 2.25A.

Your battery won't last very long.  Assuming 300mAh, you will get maybe 7 minutes out of it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is for a small robot toy. I'm shooting for 10-15 min so I'll have to try to get my current down a bit :)